# get display name for month and day in week in icu4j for islamicCalendar

Tags: java, android, icu4j

in icu4j we can get display month name by locale like this

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter
                = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy MMM dd");
        String dateString = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```

which return current date with month name in geregorian calendar.
but 
Is it Possible to get month name of Islamic months using icu4j.

Comment: Related: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/icu4j-framework.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ULocale locale = new ULocale("@calendar=islamic");
Calendar islamicCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);

// full date
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, locale);
System.out.println(df.format(islamicCalendar.getTime()));

// date in "yyyy MMM dd" format
SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy MMM dd", locale);
System.out.println(df1.format(islamicCalendar.getTime()));

// name of month 
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat (SimpleDateFormat.MONTH, locale);
System.out.println(df2.format(islamicCalendar.getTime()));

// name of weekday
SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat (SimpleDateFormat.WEEKDAY, locale);
System.out.println(df3.format(islamicCalendar.getTime()));
```

Outputs:

```
AH 1438 Rabiʻ I 5, Sun

1438 Rab. I 05

Rabiʻ I

Sun
```

If you want output to be in a specific locale, put that locale before `@calendar=islamic`:

Example for arabic locale:

```
ULocale locale = new ULocale("ar@calendar=islamic");
...
```

Outputs:

```
الأحد، ٥ ربيع الأول، ١٤٣٨ هـ

١٤٣٨ ربيع الأول ٠٥

ربيع الأول

الأحد
```